# Selenium Grid - Specified number of threads not getting fully occupied

Tags: java, ruby, multithreading, selenium, selenium-grid

I have specified the number of threads as 20 for 300 test cases. When the test run starts it occupies all the 20 threads and completes over 270+ test cases, after that the thread occupancy is getting reduced to very few and by the end it is running with single thread.

This is the same case irrespective of number of threads/number of test cases, where the last 10% of the tests are occupied with minimum number of threads even though there are more test cases to run than the number_of_threads.

Test environment:

- Selenium Grid v2.53.1
- Ruby, Cucumber, Remotewebdriver with http::persistent client

I have searched for similar issue and there is nothing i can relate to, please let me know if there is an existing issue in Selenium for this, or is there any tweaks to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This has got nothing to do with Selenium, especially the Selenium Grid. The Grid is merely an execution environment, which facilitates running your browser based UI tests in a remote environment.

It does not manage the test concurrency. You would need to check at the ruby level to figure out what is happening here.